# Matlab optimization without explicit objective function

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a problem that I want to solve with a nonlinear optimization tool of Matlab. So far I only found methods like "fmincon". But for this, you have to have an explicit objective function.

Is there a tool, for that it's not necessary to have an explicit function?

My problem looks like this:
There is the parameter t that should be minimized.

Q, A, A*: 3x3 matrix,
t       : 1x1 matrix

A = A* + Q*t

And there is a "sigma" which is calculated with A.
Sigma has to fulfill boundary conditions, e.g. sigma < 100

If someone could give me the right keywords that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: the word minimization is a short of "minimization of a function", which tends to be called "objective function". If you minimize "something", that something is your objective function. What does "minimize t" mean? Usually it means, "find me a t such that X is small" and that sentence in math mode is your objective function.

Comment: Yes, I understand. If you use e.g. "fmincon", you have to write down an explicit function, e.g. f=@(x)x(1)^2*x(2). But in my case, that is not possible. I am sure there is a method for such cases. I am looking for that.

Comment: Why is it not possible? It just seems that you don't knwo how to do, which is a very different thing that not being possible. You cant minimize a function that does not exist Your explanation if sigma is very vague, but `A = A* + Q*t` is very easily written as a minimization problem for t

Comment: I just showed you a concept so that you understand what I need. In order to be able to calculate sigma, numerous intermediate steps have to be calculated. That's why it's not possible to get a function like t=....

Comment: All those calculations together are your objective function. The input to the function is the variable to minimize, the output is the value that you want to be as small as possible. An objective function doesn’t need to be a single line or a single expression. A function can be as complex as necessary.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that.